# Cannot Start Cytoscape

Tags: java, cytoscape

This morning I downloaded Cytoscape `v3.8.0` and I can no longer successfully open the app.

Before this, I was using `v3.7.4` (I believe?) and did not encounter any issues. I am working off a laptop with Windows 10.

After realizing that I could not open Cytoscape I went and [downloaded the most recent version of Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/) but that did not appear to help.

I also tried downloading the [Cytoscape troubleshooter for Windows](https://cytoscape.org/troubleshooting.html), however, it only downloads as a `.txt` file and I cannot figure out how to use that to test my system.

If I try opening the app, it appears very quickly with `"Cytoscape 3.8.0 - Initializing OSGi container..."` before crashing.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On the text file page, try CTRL+S to save the file and it'll allow you to download the script using 'save as'. You can then run it as a .bat file and it then can be executed from there.

Comment: When I save the file, the only option it gives me is to save it as a .txt file. Even if I select to save under "All Files", my computer seems to only recognize it as text.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to diagnose your issues without a little more information, unfortunately.  When you say you downloaded the latest Java -- which version did you actually download?  If you open up a command (cmd) window and change directory to the Cytoscape install, can you try to run cytoscape.bat?  What does it do, and what error messages are printed?  If that doesn't work, in that same window, type "java -version" and let us know which version of Java is set to be the default.  That will help us figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, a recent update has caused OpenCL based Cytoscape Apps to fail and prevents Cytoscape from launching.

This will be fixed in future updates, but you can fix your Mac installation immediately by disabling OpenCL by either of the two following methods:

- Download the [disable-opencl.dummy file](https://cytoscape.org/disable-opencl.dummy) to your CytoscapeConfiguration
  directory (in your user home directory).
- Or, you can create an empty dummy file by running this command in Terminal:

  `touch ~/CytoscapeConfiguration/disable-opencl.dummy`

These fixes are described at [Cytoscape.org](https://cytoscape.org/common_issues.html#opencl).